Change MS teams working location programmatically
I'm trying to develop a simple app to dynamically set the teams working location based on the current ip address of my network.
There's not a graph API for doing that, but analyzing the network activity running teams in a browser, the endpoint used is the following:
https://presence.teams.microsoft.com/v1/me/workLocation/ (PUT)
with this body:
{
  "location": 2,
  "expirationTime": "2024-07-15T21:59:59.999Z"
}

Location can be 0 (none), 1 (work) or 2 (home)
The endpoint is secured and a bearer token is passed by the Teams web app.
The point here is, how can I obtain a valid token to call the same endpoint?
I've found a good example using power automate:https://www.loryanstrant.com/2023/06/05/automatically-change-your-microsoft-teams-working-location-with-home-assistant/
The flow works perfectly, the point is that using the flow, the authentication process is totally managed by Power Automate.
I've tried many different ways to obtain a valid token from the MSAL auth process (and, of course, registering the app in azure), using different scopes and assigning different permissions to the app registration, but testing the endpoint I always obtain a 401 not authorized error.
Please have a look to a dotnet console tester I've created, I always get a 401 when calling the final endopoint
using System;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json; 

namespace TeamsTokenApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
            var tenantId = "MY_TENANT_ID";
            var authority= $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(authority)
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            try
            {
                var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                Console.WriteLine($"Token: {result.AccessToken}");

                var token = result.AccessToken;
                var expirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5).ToString("o"); // Current time + 5 hours in ISO 8601 format

                var requestBody = new
                {
                    location = 2,
                    expirationTime = expirationTime
                };

                var jsonRequestBody =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
                var content = new StringContent(jsonRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
               
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync("https://presence.teams.microsoft.com/v1/me/workLocation/", content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Request succeeded.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Request failed. Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An interactive login is requested");
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

For your reference, here a simple power shell script I've implemented to get a valid token after authentication, none works!
Can someone please help me?
$clientId = "<MY_CLIENT_ID>"
$tenantId = "<MY TENANT_ID>"
#$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
#$scope = "https://presence.teams.microsoft.com/.default"
$scope = "https://<MY_TENANT_ID>.sharepoint.com/.default"

$authResult = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Scopes $scope -Interactive

if ($authResult.AccessToken) {
    Write-Output "Bearer $($authResult.AccessToken)"
} else {
    Write-Output "Failed to obtain the token"
}

Best regards and good coding!

Make sure you add the HTTP headers Content-Type and Accept like in the example.

When you encounter a 401 not authorized error, it usually indicates that the permissions associated with the token are incorrect or the token is not recognized by the endpoint. Could you please verify the scopes and permissions of the token and confirm that it is correctly included in the header of your PUT request?

Hi, tried with different scopes and I always have 401, the problem for sure depends on the token (or from the azure app permissions associated) and related infos inside, infact using the jwt token returned from teams web, everything works as expected.  Current Azure App permissions (all delegated on behalf of my user account): Graph: AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, TeamSettings.ReadWriteAll, User.Read, User.Read.All, Skype and Teams Tenant Admin A: user_impersonation

Noone having the same issue?

Late to the party, and you might have already found something, but I stumbled onto this workaround.
